# JavaScript compression that preserves public methods?

Tags: javascript, compression, private, public

I'm trying to minimize a library that I've created. Unfortunately, because I started developing the library several years ago, it does not use any standard way of declaring methods and private properties. Basically, my code looks like:

```
/** @class Sample abstract class. */
myname.space.AbstractClass = function() {

    /** Sample protected property A
      * @private
      */
    this.longNameProtectedPropertyA = 10;

    /** Sample protected property B
      * @private
      */
    this.longNameProtectedPropertyB = 20;
}

/** Sample public method A.
  * @methodOf myname.space.AbstractClass#
  */
myname.space.AbstractClass.prototype.publicMethodA = function() {
    return this.longNamePrivatePropertyA;
}

/** Sample public method B.
  * @methodOf myname.space.AbstractClass#
  */
myname.space.AbstractClass.prototype.publicMethodB = function() {
    return this.longNamePrivatePropertyB;
}

/** @class Sample concrete class.
  * @extends myname.space.AbstractClass
  */
myname.space.ConcreteClass = function() {

    myname.space.AbstractClass.call(this);

    /** Sample protected property C.
      * @protected
      */
    this.longNameProtectedPropertyC = 30;
}
myname.space.ConcreteClass.trickyExtend(myname.space.AbstractClass);

/** Overrides publicMethodB of the base class.
  * @methodOf myname.space.ConcreteClass# */
myname.space.ConcreteClass.prototype.publicMethodB = function() {
    return this.longNameProtectedPropertyC * this.longNameProtectedPropertyB;
}
```

In such a long example I tried to show the coding style that I use. I realize that today, it is non-standard. But my library is already written like that and it works perfectly.

Now my problem is that I want to minify the code. What I need is to compress the long names of private properties, but I need to preserve the names of public methods.

I've tried the YUI compressor and Google's Closure compiler. Neither worked as I needed. Either both private properties' and public methods' names were obfuscated, or none of them were.

Is there a way how to do that? I'm ready to spend long time by annotating hundreds of my methods/properties if it would help. Is there some minifier that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try rewriting, before minimisation, with associative syntax, eg :

```
myname.space.AbstractClass.prototype['publicMethodA'] = function() {
    return this.longNamePrivatePropertyA;
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting! May I ask why would this help? Is it because it hides the identifiers to the minimizer as they are actually strings?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. Strings (and keywords) should remain unaffected my minimisation, at least I assume so. If you want a global member to survive minimisation, then write it as eg. `window['myname']...`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for that! I've just done few experiments and it seems it will really work. The cool thing is that this can easily be done using regular expressions, saving my time!

Comment: Hey, that's good to hear. Personally I would do the edits with straightforward find/replace, sanctioning each change manually but if you are confident with regular expressions, then there's no reason they shouldn't work.